# How to use a subquery in array_agg without using a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that I would like to write **wihout using a join** and concat all phone numberes together from another table.
The phone numbers are linked together by ink_id field.

I tried these query but both of them are giving me a syntax error.

```
select
    ink.fullname,
    array_agg(select phone_number from phone_numbers where phone_numbers.ink_id = ink.id) as _phones
from
    ink
```

or

```
select
    ink.fullname,
    select(array_agg(phone_number) from phone_numbers where phone_numbers.ink_id = ink.id) as _phones
from
    ink
```

Ink table

```
+-----+------------+
| id  |  fullname  |
+-----+------------+
| 567 | John Smith |
| 159 | Caleb Doe  |
| 333 | Bill Gates |
+-----+------------+
```

Phone number table

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id | ink_id | phone_number |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 |    333 |    516519899 |
|  2 |    159 |    216584989 |
|  3 |    333 |    123149849 |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

So the result should be

```
+-----+------------+----------------------+
| id  |  fullname  |    _phone_numbers    |
+-----+------------+----------------------+
| 567 | John Smith |                      |
| 159 | Caleb Doe  | 216584989            |
| 333 | Bill Gates | 516519899, 123149849 |
+-----+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What's wrong with (left) joins?

Comment: I wanted to do it without joins but using subquery instead

Comment: The sub-query needs parentheses! `(select ... )`

Comment: @jarlh thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method would work, if you used the right syntax:

```
select ink.fullname,
       (select array_agg(pn.phone_number)
        from phone_numbers pn
        where pn.ink_id = ink.id
       ) as _phones
from ink;
```

Subqueries need to be surrounded by parentheses.